# Why does this recursive ```yield from``` function not raise an error?

Tags: python, recursion, yield, yield-from

```
def prefixes(s):
    if s:
        yield from prefixes(s[:-1])
        yield s

t = prefixes('both')
next(t)
```

The next(t) returns 'b'. I'm just confused as to why this is because if we follow down the `yield from` statement, we will eventually end at `yield from prefixes('')` which would return None. In all my other tests yield from None raises a TypeError. Instead, this seems to just be ignored and prefixes('b') moves onto the next yield statement (? why does it do that?) to yield 'b'...
Any ideas as to why? Would greatly appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

generators are lazy(on-demand) objects, you didn't exhaust your generator `t`, to exhaust your generator you can use:

```
list(t)
# ['b', 'bo', 'bot', 'both']
```

now if you use `next(t)` you will get  the expected `StopIteration`

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-680ef78477e2> in <module>
      6 t = prefixes('both')
      7 list(t)
----> 8 next(t)

StopIteration:
```

---

the `if` statement is "guaranteeing" that you have an end and you will never do `None[:-1]` to get the `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

`prefixes` is wrapped in a generator that raises `StopIteration` when the function returns. When passed an empty string, `prefixes` skips any yields, reaches the end of its code block and returns, causing `StopIteration`. The return value doesn't matter, it is discarded

```
>>> next(prefixes(""))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

`yield from` suppresses the inner generator's `StopIteration` and lets the outer generator continue.